# Adding new object to mongoDB changes the previously added object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 and MongoDB in a full-stack react application.

When I add a new recept in front-end it works normally. But once in a while it changes the rndImageName which I create on back-end. Images uploads to S3 fine.

Is there better way to do this?

```
multer.js

const randomImageName = (bytes = 32) => crypto.randomBytes(bytes).toString('hex')
let rndImageName = randomImageName();

awsRouter.post('/recipeImages', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {

  const buffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer).resize({ height: 1920, width: 1080, fit: 'contain' }).toBuffer()

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: 'recipeImages/' + rndImageName, 
    Body: buffer,
    ContentType: req.file.mimetype
  }

  const command = new PutObjectCommand(params)

  await s3.send(command)

})


recipes.js 

const { rndImageName } = require('./multer')

recipesRouter.post('/', async (request, response, next) => {

  const body = request.body

  const decodedToken = jwt.verify(getTokenFrom(request), process.env.SECRET)

  if (!decodedToken.id) {
    return response.status(401).json({ error: 'token invalid' })
  }
  const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)


  const recipe = new Recipe({
    id: body.id,
    recipe_name: body.recipe_name,
    ingredients: body.ingredients,
    instructions: body.instructions,
    speed: body.speed,
    category: body.category,
    main_ingredient: body.main_ingredient,
    diet: body.diet,
    likes: body.likes || 0,
    comments: body.comments || [],
    created: new Date(),
    imageName: rndImageName,
    user: user._id
  })

  const savedRecipe = await recipe.save()
  user.recipes = user.recipes.concat(savedRecipe._id)
  await user.save()

})
```

I want to insert the rndImageName (which I set up for S3 file name) to mongoDB objects so I can create signedUrl for a specific recipe.

Now it seems to use the same randomImageName again. Also changing the previously added recipe's imageName.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to check it on my code. But from my analysis it is only running random image name once and the function keeps running because of the server running only called the function once when it reads the file. I think you can refactor and create helper function for getting the randomImgName in different file like

randomImgNameGenerator.js

```
let currentRandom = '';

function randomImgNameGenerator (bytes = 32) {
   const randomImageName = crypto.randomBytes(bytes).toString('hex');
   currentRandom = randomImageName;

   return randomImageName;
}

function getCurrentRandom () {
   return currentRandom;
}

module.exports = {
  randomImgNameGenerator,
  getCurrentRandom
}
```

And call it inside callback in multer. Like this

```
const { randomImgNameGenerator } = require(<path to helper random name file>);

awsRouter.post('/recipeImages', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {

  const buffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer).resize({ height: 1920, width: 1080, fit: 'contain' }).toBuffer()

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: 'recipeImages/' + randomImgNameGenerator(), 
    Body: buffer,
    ContentType: req.file.mimetype
  }

  const command = new PutObjectCommand(params)

  await s3.send(command)

})

//recipes
const { getCurrentRandom } = require(<path to helper>);

//Call the function inside router callback
/**
 * Route callback here
 */
 const uploadedRandomName = getCurrentRandom();

//Save recipes to db
```

And see will it helps

**Update**

I see what you are trying to do now.

You have two handler with different route, one uploading file and one saving recipes. You can use custom middleware to handle that in one go but i am not gonna delve into details, you may have your consideration as well. If that is what you are trying to do, embed into request object will be much better. But in current case, i'd prefer to do getter function. Once again haven't check the code works or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
Still, I need to pass the created randomImageName to recipesRouter. How to do it?

Comment: You don't? The router has callback function and you don't pass anything other than response, request and next to params. You just call the function in callback. Import or require it from the file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JCC288 for your advice. I figured it out by generating awImageName in front-end and sharing awsImageName for both routers.

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault()

```
const awsImageName = randomImgNameGenerator()

handleImageAdd({file, imageSrc, awsImageName })

handleRecipeAdd({
  recipe_name: newReceptName,
  ingredients: ingredients,
  instructions: instructions,
  speed: recipespeed,
  category: category,
  main_ingredient: mainIngredient,
  diet: diets,
  imageName: awsImageName
})
```